# Chain link external api call does not work

Tags: solidity, rinkeby, chainlink

I'm trying to make external api call from my contract. I am using chain link to make this request. After transfer some tokens from one account to another it should make api request to my test requestbin API URL. But nothing happens. Here is my code example.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract Token is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
    
    string public volume;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    string public name = "Test token";
    string public symbol = "CEAI";
    

    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000;

    
    address public owner;

    
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x7AFe1118Ea78C1eae84ca8feE5C65Bc76CcF879e;
        jobId = "6d1bfe27e7034b1d87b5270556b17277";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // (Varies by network and job)
        
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Not enough tokens");

        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[to] += amount;
    
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        // Set the URL to perform the GET request on
        request.add("get", "https://en6d2u28sb3n1b4.m.pipedream.net/?test=2");
        request.add("path", "workflow_id");
        
        // Sends the request
        sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }

    
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[account];
    }
    
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, string memory _volume) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
    {
        volume = _volume;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using Rinkeby based on your tag. But the [documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/decentralized-oracles-ethereum-mainnet/) mentions that the LINK contract is in maintenance mode on Rinkeby. You could try on a different network, but you'll have to also change the Oracle Address and Job ID. You can check out the nodes and job ids in the chainlink marketplace [here](https://market.link/search/nodes).

...

Screenshot from Chainlink documentation about Rinkeby Link contract's status -
[image: Screenshot from Chainlink documentation about Rinkeby Link contract's status]